# Partition function based on Euler's formula

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to find the partitions of a number using the Euler's formula for that:

[image]

It produces results like:

```
P(3) = P(2) + P(1) = 3
P(4) = P(3) + P(2) = 3+ 2 = 5
P(5) = P(4) + P(3) - P(0) = 5 + 3 - 1 = 7
P(6) = P(5) + P(4) - P(1) = 7 + 5 - 1 = 11 and so on..
* P(0) = 1
```

It produces two positive and then two negative values and so on.

I am using recursion for that but the code goes into an infinite loop without producing any result.

```
long result = 0;
long counter = 0;

class Euler
{
public:
long Partition(long n)
{
    int exponent = 0;
    if (n < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        exponent = pow(-1, counter - 1) ;

        if (n == 0)
        {
            n = 1;
        }

        return Partition((exponent * (n - ( (counter * ( (3 * counter) - 1)) / 2)))) +   
        Partition(((exponent * (n - ( (counter * ( (3 * counter) + 1)) / 2)) )));
    }

}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    long result= 0;
    long a = 3;
    Euler * obj = new Euler();
    long s = obj->Partition(a);
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a) Don´t use floating-point pow for a +/- decision. (-1)^n with a natural number n is 1 if n is even, else -1

Comment: b) Return 0 if `n <= 0` not `n < 0`

Comment: It should be < 0 since if n == 0 this means n = 1. See below where I have defined it.

Comment: I see it in the code, but not in the formula.

Comment: It is so by convention. P(0) = 1, P(1) = 1, P(2) = 2

Comment: Then, in case n==0, why you´re calling the function recursively instead of returning the value?

Comment: It should not make any difference. It still goes into a loop.

Comment: Wait a moment, counter is a global variable?!

Comment: Yep. It increases with each recursion as per the formula. counter = k in the formula

Comment: I am more worried about the recursive part, whether it's doing what it should be doing

Comment: Well, isn´t your problem that it doesn´t do what it should do? Currently i´m (unsuccessfully) trying to get the big picture, but I can guarantee that the global stuff is trouble. Another thing: Your defined value for (at least) P(1) won´t match the formula if P(0) is 1 and P(x<0)=0

Answer (score 1):

Your global `counter` is modified by the first call to `Partition`, so the second one operates on a different one; in fact, the `counter` changes more or less unpredictably.

Do not use globals.